# WCF Rest Custom URL

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, .net-3.5

I'm trying to configure a RESTful WCF service that will accept the following url:

http://localhost/Service.svc/ProcessRequest;ID=1234

I've created the Service Contract as follows:

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface IService
    {

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/ProcessRequest")]
        XmlElement ProcessRequest(Stream postbody);
```

However, this returns a 404 error when I try and call this from the client, probably due to the format of the url.  Is there a way of handling the ;ID=1234 as part of method. I don't necessarily need to capture the value of ID, but for various reasons the client will be sending the URL in that format and I must be able to handle it.

Comment: I realize this doesn't help you much, but just so you are aware, clients are not supposed to define URLs.  The URL space is the responsibility of the server and the clients should have no say in the matter.  If the clients were using hypermedia properly this would be obvious to your client developers.

Comment: I quite agree. But what I'm doing is creating a mocked version of an existing service I'm using.

Answer (score 1):

First up, you need to remove the `/` prefix from your UriTemplate. I'm not sure if you can get away with the semi-colon, but you should try this:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "ProcessRequest;ID={id}")]
    XmlElement ProcessRequest(string id, Stream postbody);
}
```

Failing that, replace `;` with `?` and try loading it as `http://localhost/Service.svc/ProcessRequest;ID=1234` to see if that's the problem.

Comment: The last sample is wrong? Shouldn't it be:  http://localhost/Service.svc/ProcessRequest?ID=1234 ?

Comment: I can't use ? I have to use ;

Comment: Hmmm, if I add the additional parameter in the method I get the following exception: 

An ExceptionDetail, likely created by IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true, whose value is: System.InvalidOperationException: An exception was thrown in a call to a WSDL export extension: System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior contract: http://tempuri.org/:ICarService ----> System.InvalidOperationException: For request in operation ProcessRequest to be a stream the operation must have a single parameter whose type is Stream.

Comment: @Mark 909 - That's a separate issue. See this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746992/adding-querystring-parameters-to-a-wcf-service-operation-that-accepts-stream

Comment: Thanks. Just tried following the steps. Should I put the id in the method definition, if so should it go before or after the Stream parameter?

Comment: @Mark 909 - It should probably go before (ie. Stream is the last parameter), though I'm not sure if it matters.

Comment: Why do you need to lose the initial "/"? All my UriTemplate values have them, and they work fine.